# Debbuging For Vba

Tags: vba, for-loop

```
Sub CopyEstabelec()

    Dim v As String
    Dim b As String
    Dim i As Long

    i = 10

    For i = 10 To 1619
        v = Range("A" & i).Value
        If v = "Estabelecimento:" Then
            b = Range("B" & i).Value
            Range("AA" & i).Value = b
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Can someone help me to find out the reason why the code is not working? It reports that the "types" are not compatible. What I'm trying to do is to copy the value in the range("B" & i) to the range("AA" & i) if the range("A" & i) is equal to "Estabelecimento:".

Comment: First, skip the assignment to `b` altogether. Just do: `Range("AA" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value`. Second, step through the code by pressing `F8` to run it line by line and see exactly which line throws the error.

Comment: You can also do this with a formula in excel. `=IF(A1="Estabelecimento:",AA1=B1,"")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyEstabelec()

Dim v As String
Dim i As Long

For i = 10 To 1619
v = TRIM(Range("A" & i).Value)
    If v = "Estabelecimento:" Then
     Range("AA" & i) = Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `.text` may not be a good choice depending on the data in the cells. `.Text` only contains the *displayed* data, not the entire contents of the cell. So if the cell contains the data "A B C D E F G H I...", but the cell is only wide enough to display "A B C D", then the `.Text` property will contain "A B C D" while the `.Value property contains all the cells text.

Answer (score 0):

from your code I wouldn't say why is it throwing that error: *"types" are not compatible*.

you may want to add some info and/or show data that lead to that error.

I'd also suggest to follow Tim's piece of advice: step through code and query variables state. mostly you may want to type in the Immediate Window:

```
?Range("A" & i).Parent.Name, Range("A" & i).Address, Range("A" & i).Value

?Range("B" & i).Parent.Name, Range("B" & i).Address, Range("B" & i).Value
```

to see **where** you actually *are* (worksheet, address) with what value

---

while as a contribution to your code please consider the following:

use `SpecialCells()` method of `Range` object to loop through relevant cells only - in this case: cells with a "constant" (i.e.: not resulting from formulas) text value

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyEstabelec()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A10:A1619").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        If cell.Value = "Estabelecimento:" Then cell.Offset(, 26).Value = cell.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

or the same but with a formula approach:

```
Sub CopyEstabelec()
    With Range("A10:A1619").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(, 26)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1=""Estabelecimento:"", RC2,"""")"
        .Value = .Value '<~~ to keep values instead of formulas
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RafaelFM: did you get through it?